# GRUB does not list an option for windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 8.1, and after that when I boot my computer the grub menu come up and I have the option to boot Ubuntu regularly, or in safe mode, but I don't have the option to boot windows. I've tried using grub customizer, but that didn't work, so I then came here, but I just don't know what I'm doing in general, so if you could seriously dumb it down for me(like literally step by step) that would be AWESOME!

Answer (score 0):

Boot your pc into ubuntu than follow these steps
open a new Terminal, then type:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

- Press ENTER.
- Then type:

> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)

- Press ENTER.
- Than click **Recommended repair**, than wait for the process to finish, reboot your device you will find windows 8.